# Visual Studio 2010 Bookmarks problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I create bookmarks into editor code with Bookmarks window, work for a while adding methods, removing statements etc. and then I reopen the IDE the line number for bookmarks are wrong...

Any idea?

Comment: crystal balls at the ready...."look at them shine!"

Comment: not a "Mighty Boosh" fan I take it?

Comment: Yes, this is really annoying, it's because they are related to the line number not the code. Anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around this problem is to not close visual studio before finishing writing your code. The bookmarks will update if the program is still running, but will show the wrong lines if loading a save file.