# Bookmarks float in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2005

I'd liked the feature of bookmarking in Visual Studio until I figured out that the bookmarks don't ALWAYS stick to the position they used to be.

Many have [grumbled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3424053/visual-studio-2010-bookmarks-problem) about and even [reported](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/766271/bookmarks-in-code-do-not-retain-their-position-after-editing) it to MS, but it seems the problem hasn't solved yet since MS didn't mention bookmarking issue on the most recent [Visual Studio 2012 update 3](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2835600) (still, I pledge alligiance to Microsoft. =D)

I tried a trial version of ReSharper but it seemed to be way too heavy. Right clicking on the editor took seconds. Yes, my PC at work is "ancient". I didn't find out if ReSharper deals with the problem because I removed it in half an hour.

Does anyone know of any light weight add-ins or extensions for Visual Studio that provide   a bookmarking feature that is non line number based?

Any suggestion or workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resharper bookmarking system is really nice. You can create a bookmark by ctrl+shift+#(1,2,3 etc) then you can jump to it by pressing ctrl+# (Very handy stuff). About it being heavy, you should disable all resharper features, especially the intellisense stuff, autocomplete things, code analysis and all that. Maybe your work pc can handle it after all.

Comment: Seems Resharper is the only solution so far. I'll give it a try once again having set all other features off.Thank you.